# Bootstrap datetimepicker change disabled days after initialisation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I try to change the disabled days after the datetimepicker is initialised.

I do this with an ajax call but I tried to simplify the code.
I tried `$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()`
for the `FUNCTION` I tried `.disableddates`, `.setDisabledDates`.

The first one erased the formerly declared disabled dates but did not add new ones.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/nl.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button class="btn button-default" onclick="ChangeDate()" >Change disabled days</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
          locale:"nl",
          defaultDate: "2017-06-25",
          disabledDates: ['2017-06-26','2017-06-27','2017-06-28'],
          debug: false                    
        });
      });

      function ChangeDate(){
        alert('ChangeDate geklikt !');
        $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").disabledDates(['2017-06-21','2017-06-22']);
        alert('functie is uitgevoerd !');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

As the docs states [`disabledDates`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#endisableddates):

> Takes an `[` `string` or `Date` or `moment` `]` of values and disallows the user to select those days.

If you pass an array of `strings` each element should be compatible with datetimepicker [`format`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option (in your case the default `L LT` which is `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm` for `nl` locale).

The issue is that the datepicker `disabledDates` function does:

```
moment('2017-06-21', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')
```

that parses the input string as `2021-06-20` (disabled instead of `2017-06-21`).

You can simply convert your array string to an array of moment object using [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) parsing function (note that your input string is in ISO 8601 compliant format recognized by moment).

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  locale:"nl",
  defaultDate: "2017-06-25",
  disabledDates: ['2017-06-26','2017-06-27','2017-06-28'],
  debug: false
});

function ChangeDate(){
  //alert('ChangeDate geklikt !');
  $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").disabledDates([
    moment('2017-06-21'),
    moment('2017-06-22')
  ]);
  //alert('functie is uitgevoerd !');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/nl.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn button-default" onclick="ChangeDate()" >Change disabled days</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another way to fix the issue is to add the [`extraFormats: ['YYYY-MM-DD']`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#extraformats) option to datetimepicker config to tell the component how to parse correctly strings like `'2017-06-21'` and `'2017-06-22'`.

Comment: Great !!! thank you very much, it toke me days. But I get the dates from my json webservice like "2017-07-11T00:00:00.0000000", how can I use these?

Comment: You can parse your date using moment as described in the answer (`moment("2017-07-11T00:00:00.0000000"`) or add `extraFormats: ['YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS']`.

Comment: Sorry I dont get i to work. I get values from the webservice like '2017-06-29 00:00:00Z' the min and maxValues are set correctly but the disabledDates are not set. The disabledDates is an array with dates in the same format. In the datetimepicker I set the format to ` format: ("DD-MM-YYYY"),          locale: 'nl',extraFormats: ['YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'],` and after initialisation I do `jQuery('#datepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").disabledDates(pDisabledDays);`

Comment: Since you are getting values like `'2017-06-29 00:00:00Z'`, I suggest to use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), in your case something like `moment.utc('2017-06-29 00:00:00Z')` (foreach element of the array).

Comment: do you mean I have to reformat the whole array to "DisabledDays":[moment.utc("2017-06-29 00:00:00Z"),moment.utc("2017-06-30 00:00:00Z"),.....]  etc ? What format does the datetTimepicker accept in the array ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I suggested in my last comment (and in the first part of my answer). The datetimepicker tries to convert each string of the `disabledDates` array to moment using the format passed to `format` option (in your case default value `L LT` => `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm`) and each format in the [`extraFormat`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#extraformats) option.